# Azure AD B2C Why Continue Button is not working when I add Display Control on password reset?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I've created a display control for email validation to display it on password reset.

[image]

[image]

I am using a REST API to send the email verification code and verify the code as well.

but I notice after I added the display control to my flow the Save/Continue button is not working.

Can some please explain to me what is the issue is?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Browser console? Also what are you using to **generate** a code to pass to the REST API which sends the code to the email address?

Comment: @JasSuri there is not error in the Browser console. I am using rnd.Next(11243, 99635) to generate the code in the REST API

Comment: are you using any HTML/css for continue button??
i to faced similar issue.

Comment: @RohitChouhan No,I am using the built-in continue button.. it works if I don't have the display control